# PHP regex pattern

Tags: php, regex

I'm trying to get the unique ID from a string using PHP regex but I'm having problems generating the regex pattern.

sample urls

```
lesson-computer-networking-xpt2-t9295779.html // need to get 9295779
lesson-summary-t9295778.html //need to get 9295778
lesson-part2-t94.html //need to get 94
```

The length of first portion of the string depends on the page title but last portion is always `-txxxxxxxx.html`

Can someone help me to generate the pattern?

Comment: @kingkero The problem is that I have no idea about regex patterns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the below regex to get the number after `t` which was before `.html`,

```
-t\K\d+(?=\.html)
```

OR

```
(?<=-t).*(?=\.html)
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/oE7wM6/6)

Your PHP code would be,

```
<?php
$data = <<<'EOT'
lesson-computer-networking-xpt2-t9295779.html
lesson-summary-t9295778.html
lesson-part2-t94.html
EOT;
$regex = '~(?<=-t).*(?=\.html)~';
preg_match_all($regex, $data, $matches);
var_dump($matches);
?>
```

Output:

```
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  array(3) {
    [0]=>
    string(7) "9295779"
    [1]=>
    string(7) "9295778"
    [2]=>
    string(2) "94"
  }
}
```

**Explanation:**

- `(?<=-t)` A lookbehind is used to look after specific pattern. In our case the regex engine should set the matching marker just after to the string `-t`.
- `.*(?=\.html)` Next it matches all the characters upto the string `.html`(ie, when `.html` is seen by the regx engine, it suddenly stops the matching)

Comment: Thanks for the pattern! Appreciate it.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, what if the URL is  `lesson-tpart2-t94.html`

Comment: Page title is generated upon user input so if user enters some word stating with the letter T that would conflict with the unique ID field.

Comment: @NaveenGamage then use this regex http://regex101.com/r/oE7wM6/7

Answer (score 2):

this is my pattren

```
-t(\d+)\.html
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use something like this:

```
$url = 'lesson-computer-networking-xpt2-t9295779.html';
$matches = array();
$t = preg_match('/-t(.*?)\.html$/s', $url, $matches);
print_r($matches[1]);
```